# Timer unable to run in Android Service

Tags: android, timer

My timer doesn't work in android service.The service is able to send first message but it doesn't send message in each timer interval.

```
public class AutoStartUp extends Service
{
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startTimer();
    }


    public void startTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();

        initializeTimerTask();

        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 10000); //
    }


    public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                        final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strDate, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I received Service Started in toast.

Comment: I copied your code and ran it on a Lollipop device.  It produced the periodic toasts.  Add `onDestroy()` to your code with a toast or log message to see if something is causing your service to be killed.

Comment: brother , code works fine if its not a SERVICE .. did you run it as a service and run in background ??

Comment: Yes, it's running as a service.  I copied your code without change.  I put the app in the background and it is still running.  What type of device and API level are you using?

Comment: Don't know what to suggest.  Just ran your code as a service on a Moto X with API 23 and it produced the periodic toasts when app was in foreground and background.

Comment: I'm starting the service using `Context.startService()`.  How are you starting it?